# Intersection form of $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

This comes from Vakil 20.2 C, self-study.

We have to show the intersection form of $X = \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ is given by $l \cdot l = m \cdot m = 0$ and $l \cdot m = 1$, where $l$ is the curve $\mathbb P^1 \times \{0\}$ and $m$ is the curve $\{0\} \times \mathbb P^1$.

By exercise 20.2 A, we see $l \cdot l = h^0(l, \mathcal O_l)$. I suppose if we could show this was a negative degree line bundle, we would be done by 19.2.3, but I do not see why that should be the case.

We also have just proven Adjunction: given a curve $C$ in a smooth projective surface $X$,  if $K_X$ is the canonical divisor, then

$$C\cdot (K_X + C) = 2g_C - 2$$

where $g_C$ is the genus of $C$. Right after that (and right before this problem), we showed Riemann-Roch for Surfaces:

If $D$ is a Weil divisor on $X$, where $X$ is as above, then

$$\chi(X, \mathcal O_X(D)) = \frac{D \cdot (D - K_X)}{2} + \chi(X, \mathcal O_X)$$

How do I finish?

Comment: There is something wrong in your assertion $l\cdot l=h^0(l,O_l)$. Do you know the class of $K_X$?

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by class in this instance.

Comment: $K_X$ is $al+bm$ for some integers $a,b$. Do you know $a,b$?

Comment: Do you mean has it been given to us or have I figured it out myself? The answer is no to both as far as I'm aware, but are you asking me this as if it's a hint or as if to see what tools we have been given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is wrong, we don't have $l \cdot l = h^0(l, \mathcal O_l)$. Indeed in this case $l \cdot l = 0$ and $h^0(l, \mathcal O_l) = 1$.

Actually you don't need so much machinery. It's easy to see that $\mathbb P^1 \times \{ p\}$ is linearly equivalent to $\mathbb P^1 \times \{ q\}$ for any $p,q \in \mathbb P^1$. By basic properties of intersection product, you obtain $l \cdot l = 0$.

If you want to use the adjunction formula, then as Mohan suggests you can try to compute the canonical class. To do this, you can notice that $\Omega_X \cong p_1^* \Omega_{X_1} \oplus p_2^* \Omega_{X_2}$ if $X = X_1 \times X_2$ and $p_i : X_i \to X$ is the projection.

Comment: I think your first explanation makes great sense to me: we know intersection product is independent of linear equivalence class, so we can replace on copy of $l$ by some other $\mathbb P^1 \times \{p\}$ where $p$ is not the origin, which kind of moves the line off of itself. But then the scheme theoretic intersection of the "new" $l$ with the "old" $l$ is just empty, so the product is $0$ using my initial formula. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it's correct ! (It's important to notice that the intersection is transverse so the argument can applies)

Comment: @JohnnyApple : but really $h^0(l, \mathcal O_l) = 1$ and not zero. So maybe the exercise you mention doesn't apply here ?

Comment: Why is it one in this case? Is it because of Bezout's Theorem?

Comment: @JohnnyApple : Bézout only works for $\mathbb P^2$ I think